# Assign location from Profile2 to a node

Tags: entities

I would like to allow user when creating new content (an event) to assign (from drop down) one of the locations defined in his profile (Profile2)... Is there a module which could help? If not any hint how to solve it in custom module? 
Im thinking entity reference field could do if it was possible to create list of location for each user... 
Maybe it is simple but beyond my drupal skills... ;)
Locations are nodes referenced with entity reference but not necessarily created by the same user

Comment: I suppose locations are stored as nodes? Do users create those locations by themselves? I'm thinking of some solutions but I need to be sure how your system works beforehand ;)

Comment: use form_alter() to populate the dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Install the [references](https://www.drupal.org/project/references) module, once you done that, you can enable the `node_reference` submodule and attach a "Node Reference" field to your "event" content type. Choose the "select list" widget and the user will be able to link any location to the event.

If you want to let the user choose only from locations he created, here's a way:

On the field configuration page, you can see a fieldset called "Views - Nodes that can be referenced". It says that options from the dropdown can be filtered based on a view using the "References" display type.

Just create a view listing location nodes and select the correct "display type" as shown below:

[image: Create a view with References display type]

And display nodes from the current logged-in user by adding a contextual filter "Content: Author uid"

[image: Creation of contextual filter]

Save all that and refresh the field configuration page. Select the view from the dropdown list that just appeared and you should be good to go ;).

Comment: im using entity reference on the site already... it makes little sense to install references too, dont you think? thanks for your help thou :)

Comment: Oh, I read the question thinking entity reference was only a suggestion, my bad. If you still need help, I'll take some time to update the answer ;)

Comment: Entity reference can do it in a similar way. Not sure what the display type was called again, but you'll recognise it.

Comment: Yep, I just saw that on a project I'm working for, it's pretty much the exact same thing.